# C function doesn't return string, though it should

Tags: c, return, cs50

I'm super new in C, trying to solve CS50's credit problem here.
So I wrote a function, that should check some parameters, and return a string, which I use in the main function to print an answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>


int lunh(long n);
char* check(long nu);


int main(void)
{
    long number = get_long("Number: ");
    printf("%s", check(number));
}


int lunh(long n)
{
    int length, step_one, num;
    long tens;
    step_one = 0;
    length = floor(log10(labs(n))) + 1;
    for (int i = length, powering = 1; i > length / 2; i--)
    {
        tens = pow(10, powering);
        num = ((n / tens) % 10) * 2;
        if (floor(log10(abs(num))) + 1 > 1)
        {
            while (num)
            {
                step_one += num % 10;
                num /= 10;
            }
            step_one += num;
            powering += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            step_one += num;
            powering += 2;
        }
    }
    for (int i = length, powering = 0; i > length / 2; i--)
    {
        tens = pow(10, powering);
        num = ((n / tens) % 10);
        step_one += num;
        powering += 2;
    }
    if (step_one % 10 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


char* check(long nu)
{
    int l, first_two_digits, first_one;
    l = floor(log10(labs(nu))) + 1;
    first_one = nu / 1000;
    first_two_digits = nu / 100;
    char* answer = NULL;
    if (l == 15)
    {
        if (first_two_digits == 34 || first_two_digits == 37)
        {
            if (lunh(nu) == 1)
            {
                answer = "AMEX";
            }
            else
            {
                answer = "INVALID";
            }
        }
    }
    else if (l == 13 || first_one == 4)
    {
        if (lunh(nu) == 1)
            {
                answer = "VISA";
            }
        else
        {
            answer = "INVALID";
        }
    }
    else if (l == 16)
    {
        if (first_two_digits == 51 || first_two_digits == 52 || first_two_digits == 53 || first_two_digits == 54 || first_two_digits == 55)
        {
            if (lunh(nu) == 1)
            {
                answer = "MASTERCARD";
            }
            else
            {
                answer = "INVALID";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        answer = "INVALID";
    }
    printf("%s", answer);
    return answer;
}
```

Input: 4003600000000014
Expected output: "VISA"
Current output: nothing, after inputting the number, the program stops.

Comment: Show sample input, the observed output, the output you expect instead, and explain what you mean by “doesn't return string.” Provide a [mre]. Also, edit your post so that it asks a question, preferably using a sentence that is phrased as a question and that ends with a question mark.

Comment: Looks to me like an `enum` would be a better choice for return value type here than `char*`.

Comment: @blur It seems the function returns an empty string that was initially used to initialize  the pointer answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil input is a card number, there is another function that verifies the checksum of a card number, and returns 0 if invalid and 1 if valid, and it working fine (returns what expected)

Comment: You need to show sample input exactly—**specific** input—not give a description of it. And provide sample output, copied and pasted **exactly**. And show the output you expect instead. And paste into the question a **complete** program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil will do that sir, sorry for my inattention

Comment: @blur `long` may be of insufficient range for `4003600000000014`.  Suggest `long long`.

Comment: <Expected output: "VISA"> is unclear.  With `first_two_digits = 4003600000000014 / 100;` the quotient 40036000000000 is not true with `first_two_digits == 34 || first_two_digits == 37`

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is here:  `else if (l == 13 || first_one == 4)`. From the spec:

> - Visa uses 13- and 16-digit numbers.
> - Visa numbers all start with 4

That if test will produce VISA if length is 13 *or* card starts with 4. The sample input is a 16 digit number.